# How to get the YEAR from Date Column in Progress 4 GL?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I have a column having date format in DD/MM/YYYY format in Progress 4 GL.
How can I extract YEAR from this column.

DISP YEAR(column_name) does not return anything.

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1):

You really should show your real code and provide the actual data definitions.

And the actual text of error messages.  Even if you think they are meaningless.

Just because the data is formatted like a date doesn't mean it is actually stored as a date.  This sounds like it is probably a character field with a converted date stored.  Although if that were the case you should have also seen an error message.

Does

```
display substring( column_name, 7, 4 ).
```

show you the result that you are hoping for?

Answer (score 0):

If you have **standard format DD/MM/YYYY**, then you could extract year value with :

```
DEFINE VARIABLE strYear AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.

/* Convert it to date again when you need to store it to DB */
strYear = ENTRY(3, STRING(column_name), "/").
DISP strYear.
```